# How to check if a migration needs to be ran or did run with fluent migrator?

Tags: fluent-migrator

Using FluentMigrator, is there way to find out if the MigrateUp() function will indeed migrate something or whether it's already up to date?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no easy way to tell using the public api whether the `MigrateUp` method will do something or not.

However, there are multiple "other" ways around this that depend on the internals of FluentMigrator:

- Derive from the `MigrationRunner`, override the `ApplyMigrationUp` method, which gets called every time a migration gets applied, and track/log the applied migrations
- Create a custom `IAnnouncer` implementation, configure FluentMigrator to use it through the `IRunnerContext` and in your announcer `Say` method check that the `message` parameter contains the text `"migrated"` which means a migration step has been applied.
- Look at the pending migrations before running `MigrateUp`, if you can get a reference on a `MigrationRunner` you can:

```cs
    MigrationRunner runner = ... // get a reference to the runner
    if (runner.MigrationLoader.LoadMigrations() // get all the migrations
            .Any(pair => !runner.VersionLoader
                                .VersionInfo.HasAppliedMigration(pair.Key)))
            // check which migrations have been applied
    {
         // there are pending migrations, do your logic here
    }
```